# count of id on status coloumn with sum of particular rows count using GROUP BY IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am having the following mysql table

```
id  status
------------
1   available
2   hold
3   available
4   so-hold
5   so-hold
6   hold
7   hold
8   available
```

When I use `GROUP BY` on `STATUS` coloumn I got the following :

```
count(id)   status
---------------------
3           available
3           hold
2           so-hold
```

Under `status` coloumn **'hold'** and **'so-hold'** belongs to the same category so I need count in the following manner :

```
count(id)   status
---------------------
3           available
5           hold
```

Following is the MySQL query that I am using currently :

```
SELECT count(id), status FROM `inventory_master` GROUP BY status
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CASE` statement

```
select 
count(id),
case when status = 'so-hold'
     then 'hold'
     else status
end as status_col
from inventory_master
group by status_col
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94df2/4)

Comment: @user1696621 i have used `case` statement to change the value of column for query so when status is so-hold the new alias `status_col` will show hold instead of so hold [see demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94df2/9) , then i have used count to calculate id for each distinct value in `status_col` so there will only 2 values `available,hold` and group by status_col to get the count per group

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing "so-" with empty string and then try your query as below:

```
SELECT newStatus, COUNT(*)
FROM
(SELECT REPLACE(status, 'so-', '') as newStatus
 FROM MYTABLE) AS tab
 GROUP BY newStatus
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(*), status FROM table WHERE status NOT IN('hold', 'so-hold') GROUP BY status
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*), 'hold' FROM table WHERE status IN('hold', 'so-hold')
```

At first you `COUNT` normal groups and after that `UNION` with `COUNT` for two subgroups `hold` + `so-hold`.

#### [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/94df2/5)

Comment: No its adding hold+so-hold...its displaying hold with 2 rows

Comment: @user1696621 : It's a typo, just remove the `GROUP BY` clause from the second `SELECT`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case in this situation:

```
select status, count(*) from `inventory_master`  group by case status when 'so-hold' then 'hold' else status end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Two steps. First (Sub-Select replaces 'so-hold' to 'hold') using CASE. Second step GROUP BY.

```
SELECT g1.status, COUNT(*)
  FROM ( SELECT CASE status
                 WHEN 'so-hold' THEN 'hold'
                 ELSE status
                END AS status,
                id
           FROM test_tw
        ) g1
GROUP BY g1.status
ORDER BY g1.status;
```

(tested with ORACLE)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select Case When status='So-Hold' Then 'Hold' Else status End,COUNT(*) 
From TableName
Group by Case When status='So-Hold' Then 'Hold' Else status End
```